# MulitGrid with Child Grids Contents being sized accordingly

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I dont know if this has been answered but what i am trying to to do is i have a parentGrid with 3 rows, the first two are a menu strip and a  toolbar, the third row is a child grid that is populated with the choices that are selected from the tool bar.  the problem is that i want the forms that load in the child grid to not have their height surpass what i have set that row equal to in the parentGrid.

is there an effective way to do this?

here is basically what i have for code

```
<Grid x:Name="ParentGrid" Margin="0" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="22"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="90"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="544*"></RowDefinition>
        <!--516<RowDefinition Height="80*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>-->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DockPanel></DockPanel><!--Dock Panel Menu Strip-->
    <DockPanel></DockPanel><!-- Dock Panel ToolBar-->

    <Grid x:Name="ChildGrid" Grid.Row="2" Height="544">
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: This did not work.  i think it is because the form that is being called is being placed inside the child grid and that is where i want to make sure that the form meets its size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was that instead of using a `Grid` as the inner child i used a `ScrollViewer` as the container

Answer (score 0):

Set the Height in your RowDefinition to whatever you want your Grid's height to be, then create an extra RowDefinition with a `Height="*"` to take up the remaining space

```
<Grid x:Name="ParentGrid" Margin="0" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="22"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="90"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="544"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DockPanel></DockPanel><!--Dock Panel Menu Strip-->
    <DockPanel></DockPanel><!-- Dock Panel ToolBar-->

    <Grid x:Name="ChildGrid" Grid.Row="2">
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

The `*` in your RowDefinitions mean "all remaining space". Adding a number to it defines the ratio of remaining space that column will get. For example, if you say one column is going to be `1*` and another is going to be `2*`, it means the 2nd column is going to take up twice the space as the first one. If you have one column taking up `544*` and another taking up `10*`, it means the available space will get split into 554 parts, and 544 parts will get given to the first column and 10 parts will be given to 2nd column.